# Matplotlib - remove RectangleSelector widget from the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a visual PyQt5 application which creates and shows Matplotlib plots. I want to be able to select some points on the plot with a mouse. I use `RectangleSelector` widget for it. The problem is, the drawn rectangle stays on plot after I release the mouse. Using `interactive=False` makes the rectangle invisible, but it is still there and breaks plot auto scale when I try to change the data to display on the plot. Here is the example with `interactive=True` :
[image: Selecting points]

After I load some other data to plot:
[image: The rectangle remains there outside of new data range]

Is there any way to remove the `RectangleSelector` from the plot? Or at least to make `ax.autoscale()` ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "escape" key to clear the current shape. This can be redefined in the argument `state_modifier_keys`. For details see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector).

Comment: It also makes the rectangle invisible, not actually removes it.

Answer (score 0):

A other way of doing it would be to this:

```
rectangle = RectangleSelector(...)

for artist in rectangle :
    artist.set_visible(False)
rectangle.update()
```

this is what is done when the escape button is pressed and it will remove the current rectangle selector from your graph.

Comment: I tried this code, and I get the following error: 

TypeError: 'RectangleSelector' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've resolved this yet.
I use this

```
    def line_select_callback(self, eclick, erelease):
        # At the beginning
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
        toggle_selector.RS.to_draw.set_visible(False)
        toggle_selector.RS.update()
        #....line_select_callback code....
        # Last line of method/function
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)
```